# How to remove VCRUNTIME140_1.dll connection

Tags: visual-c++

Somehow a library built in MSVC 2022 depends on MSVC 2015 runtime and I would like to sever this connection buy removing or replacing a part of code. How to locate it?

DLL dump:

```
   .....
    Imports from VCRUNTIME140_1.dll
                      __CxxFrameHandler4
```

The error window:

[image]

Comment: Have you used Dependency Walker to figure out *why* it depends on that module?

Comment: Nope, I got a lot of source and MAKE files, will it work with it?

Comment: Try it and see.

Comment: You don't actually have a dependency on the VS2015 runtime.  Microsoft promised to make runtime DLLs binary-compatible, starting with v140.  Removing a very significant headache for C++ devs.  But things change, beyond the C++xx language versions, you got this dependency because you built the x64 flavor and used VS2019 version 16.3+, they [improved exception handling](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/making-cpp-exception-handling-smaller-x64/).  Afaik there's no opt-out option.

Comment: @Hans Thank you for explanations! However I understood almost nothing except that there is no an easy workaround with slight changes if you build 64 bit dll with vc2019+. Am I correct?